# Evaluation of "something <- stuff" statements

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, operator-precedence

Is it true that statements like `something <- stuff` are always evaluated in Haskell, even when `something` is not called in the rest of the code ? (is `something <- stuff` called an "action" ? - I don't know the technical wording).

If this is true, I have another question.

I have some code starting like this:

```
computeContour3d voxel voxmax level = do
    voxelmax <- somefunction voxel
    let max' = fromMaybe voxelmax voxmax
```

That is, if the argument `voxmax` is not `Nothing`, then `voxelmax` is not necessary, since `max' = fromJust voxmax` in this case. Therefore, if the answer to my first question is "Yes", how could I avoid the evaluation of `voxelmax` when it is not necessary ?

Comment: No not per se, that depends on the monad that is used. In fact for a `Maybe` monad for example it is very likely that a huge amount is *not* evaluated. For an I/O monad, there is a guarantee that the I/O *actions* are done in the order you specify.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `somefunction voxel` returns an `IO (something)`

Comment: Well then it is guaranteed that the I/O actions are done in the order you define. But that does not per se means that all the calculations that happen around those I/O actions (at the level of Haskell) are done.

Comment: Specifically if you are in `IO`, if you want to lazily perform an action, you can use [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=unsafeInterleaveIO).  This is not common though -- it's considered better design to push all the important stuff out of `IO` into pure code, which is always as lazy as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, monadic binding is no guarantee that anything gets evaluated. There are lazy monads; e.g. the reader monad would not force the result of `somefunction voxel` unless `voxmax` was `Nothing`.

But there's no reason to rely on such behaviors; it is easy to reliably avoid extra computation:

```
computeContour3d voxel voxmax level = do
    max' <- case voxmax of
        Nothing -> somefunction voxel
        Just max -> return max
    -- use max'
```

You could consider using `maybe`, which is often shorter than an explicit `case`, as in:

```
    max' <- maybe (somefunction voxel) return voxmax
```

Comment: Ah ok. `somefunction` returns an `IO`, I didn't think to use `<-` with a `return` in the other case. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that statements like something <- stuff are always evaluated in Haskell, even when something is not called in the rest of the code ?

Not in general, no. The `IO` monad forces such evaluation, but many others do not.

> is `something <- stuff` called an "action" ?

Usually that line would be called a monadic *bind*. Some monads (e.g. lists) don't really "act" in any meaningful way.